# Why does filters in Swift iterate the collection twice?

Tags: swift

The following code in Swift's playground or Console App:

```
let letters = ["A", "B", "C"]

letters.filter({
    (x : String) -> Bool in
    println("PRINT: \(x)")
    return true
})
```

Prints out:

```
PRINT: A
PRINT: B
PRINT: C
PRINT: A
PRINT: B
PRINT: C
```

Why does it iterate over the collection twice?

Comment: Is it not the case that the REPL is printing the result of the `filter` method?

Comment: No, it is executing the closure 6 times

Comment: To be fair, the spec of `filter` doesn't specify how many times it executes the closure...

Comment: This sounds like most likely a bug. I'd tell Apple.

Comment: There is also a global `filter` method in the header, but I have not figured out how to use it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most probably `filter` is implemented to first count the number of elements it needs to store and then, after using that number to size the allocation of storage for a new array, looping again to copy the ones he needs to keep.

The fact that it loops only once if you always return `false` means that it optimizes away the second cycle iff the result is empty.

You may want to radar this as a bug but it probably is "working as designed": arrays are not lists, after all.

Comment: Your answer fits the fact so tightly, I am pretty sure that's exactly what happens under the hood. Best reply so far +1. But shouldn't Apple's implementation just allocate a resulting array as big as the source array and then change its capacity at the end? There would be no need to iterate twice.

Comment: They could. They didn't. It's an implementation choice. Depending on other implementation details it may or may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 7):

It is modified in beta 5. It is now traveling only once now, printing `ABC` instead of `ABCABC`

Answer (score 1):

`filter` returns an array which is being printed out by the playground.

```
/// Return a Array containing the elements `x` of `self` for which
/// `includeElement(x)` is `true`
func filter(includeElement: (T) -> Bool) -> T[]
```

I believe the `(6 times)` is incorrect because if you look below it `true` only gets returned 3 times.

EDIT: The above is **incorrect**.

From playing around with it more, I can only say that this is simply the behaviour of the `filter` function.

```
letters.reverse().filter({
    (x : String) -> Bool in
    println("PRINT: \(x)")
    return true
})
```

This prints `CBACBA` so its simply always traversing the array in order, twice.

```
letters.filter({
        (x : String) -> Bool in
        println("PRINT: \(x)")
        if (x == "A") {
           return true
        }
        return false
    })
```

This still prints `ABCABC`, so go figure..

I'll go ask a Swift engineer in a bit and get back to you on why this is! (If they know :p)

Comment: It's the same result in a Console Application as well, I've updated the example to show that it's the `println` that's getting called twice for each item

Comment: @mythz Ah you are right, my answer is incorrect. Let me dig into it a bit though

Comment: @mythz I know you're right because if you add another `println` right below the previous one the output is `AABBCCAABBCC`

Comment: Curiously enough, it only runs it once each if you always `return false`