# Swift extends determined generics type without using objc bindings

Tags: arrays, generics, dictionary, swift

I wanted to try implementing message pack in pure swift. Everything worked well until I came to Array.

The approach I had was to implement a protocol called `MsgPackMarshable` thats primitiv types extended :

```
 //Protocol
 protocol MsgPackMarshable{

    func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>
}

//Implementation for some types
extension UInt8 : MsgPackMarshable{
    func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>{

        return [0xcc, self]
    }
}

extension UInt16 : MsgPackMarshable{
    func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>{

        let bigEndian: UInt16 = self.bigEndian
        return [0xcd, Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF00) >> 8), Byte(bigEndian & 0x00FF)]
    }
}

extension UInt32 : MsgPackMarshable{
    func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>{

        let bigEndian: UInt32 = self.bigEndian
        return [0xce, Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF000000) >> 24), Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF0000) >> 16), Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF00) >> 8), Byte(bigEndian & 0x00FF)]
    }
}
```

I had some troubles extending `Array`. I wanted to verify dynamically that the type of the array were implementing the `MsgPackMarshable` protocol:

```
extension Array: MsgPackMarshable{
    func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>{

        for item in self{

           //How to check type here?
        }
                    return []
    }
}
```

Due to the fact that `Array` is a struct in swift, I wanted to avoid redefining a new type of `Array<MsgPackMarshable>` that embeds an Array.

Comment: Unrelated to your array problem, but note that for UInt16/32 you have to right-shift by 8, 16, or 24, not by 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: So stupid I am :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter `T` from the type being extended (ie `Array`) is in scope and can be used to determine the type. Use [the `is` operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_444) to do type checking (`T is yourtype`).

Comment: Hm; [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047164/extension-of-constructed-generic-type-in-swift).

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the `is` operator on a non @objc protocol. The error is : cannot downcast from 'T' to non-@objc protocol type 'MsgPackMarshable'

Comment: Very weird. I can't find anything that speaks directly to this without making a function that has an extra constraint where T is constrained to an additional protocol. Maybe you could use the `MsgPackMarshable` protocol.

Comment: What do you mean by "Maybe you could use the MsgPackMarshable protocol?"

Comment: You're already making various objects conform to the `MsgPackMarshable` protocol. If you use a [type constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_243) on the function (`<T: MsgPackMarshable>`) to say that T must conform to that protocol, you know that all the items conform to `MsgPackMarshable` and you have those methods available to you in the for loop. It doesn't help you in knowing exactly which type, but you can call the methods.

Comment: That only seems to work if the function is global.  I haven't been able to find a syntax that adds constraints to a generic type and says, in effect, this function only exists in the generic if this condition is met.  A similar problem arises if you try to implement an extension on Array that adds a `uniqueItems` method, but only on Arrays where T: Comparable.