# Swift - Extension on a Generic typed class/structure?

Tags: generics, swift

How do I add an extension method to a generic typed class, and access the generic type defined on the class to make the method typesafe?

The following method gives a compile error because T is not the same generic type defined on the class.

```
extension Array {
   mutating public func addTwo<T>(object: T) {
      append(object)
      append(object)
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extend typed Arrays in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the `<T>`. You can reference `T`, or equivalently `Element`, inside the extension scope without it.

Comment: Why is it T? Is it because they used the key T as the generic type? If they used K instead I would have used K? So basically I need to see the source code in order to see what the generic type is referred to as?

Comment: Is it possible to accept an argument of type T which is also Equatable?

Comment: For that reason you may prefer to use `Element` which is a typealias in the generic definition. Your other question is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047164/extension-of-constructed-generic-type-in-swift).

Answer (score 0):

The definition for `Array` uses `T` as a type parameter; thus, you have access to it in any extensions you might add to `Array`.  In your case, the following works:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> extension Array { 
  2.     mutating public func addTwo (obj: T) { append(obj); append(obj) } 
  3. }    
  4> class Foo {}
  5> var ar:[Foo] = []
ar: [Foo] = 0 values
  6> ar.addTwo(Foo())
  7> ar
$R0: [Foo] = 2 values {
  [0] = {}
  [1] = {}
}
```

Note that because the definition of `Array` has `typealias Element = T` you can use `Element` too (for readability).