# Limiting Array extension to a particular Array type?

Tags: ios, swift, sktexture

Is it possible when writing an extension to `Array` to limit the extension just to a particular `Array` type? What I am trying to do is add an extension to `Array` that only works on Arrays of type `[SKTexture]`.

I don't want the extension to do anything with Arrays containing other types (i.e. `[Int]`, `[Double]`, `[String]`, etc.)

Comment: You can't, sadly. I also desire this functionality. Some of the better attempts exist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047164/extension-of-constructed-generic-type-in-swift

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will have a look.

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value (possible duplicate?) From the top-voted answer: *"You cannot write a method on a generic type that is more restrictive on the template."*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above that it is not possible to write an extension like this, but wanted to suggest using a global function instead, with the option of currying it for greater flexibility.

For some background information, see [this blog post by Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) where he notes that in Swift,

> Instance methods are just curried functions that take the instance as the first argument.

So from Swift's point of view there is no difference between `instance.function()` and `function(instance)()`.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but a global function that looks like this...

```
func skTextureFunc(textures: [SKTexture])(arg: SomeArgType) { }
```

...is, for all intents and purposes, exactly the same as an instance method that can be bound to a particular instance of `[SKTexture]`.

And if you want, you can partially apply the function to a specific instance of `[SKTexture]` that you will be using repeatedly and then use it as if it were an instance method bound to that instance. So, for example:

```
class Example {
    var localSKTextureFunc: SomeArgType -> () {
        return skTextureFunc(textureArray)
    }

    let textureArray = [SKTexture]()
}
```

So globally you can always use the curried function, and locally (inside a class) you can bind the curried function to a specific instance of a class.

I know that's not exactly what you asked, but I think it is the best work around for the fact that we can't write extensions like the one you describe.