# Swift: Extending Array with typed function doesn't work

Tags: swift

I have a problem with an extension on Array, I'm trying to add a method to detect if there are any duplicates, if I make it a global function it works, however, when I try to make it a method in an Array extension it complains:

```
extension Array {
    static func hasDuplicates<T:Hashable>(array:Array<T>) -> Bool {
        var map = Dictionary<T,Bool>()

        for var x = 0; x < array.count; x++ {
            let currentItem = array[x] as T
            if map[currentItem] {
                return true
            } else {
                map[currentItem] = true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

func hasDuplicates<T:Hashable>(array:Array<T>) -> Bool {
    var map = Dictionary<T,Bool>()

    for var x = 0; x < array.count; x++ {
        let currentItem = array[x] as T
        if map[currentItem] {
            return true
        } else {
            map[currentItem] = true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func testDuplicates() {
    var arrayWithDuplicates = [ "not repeated", "is repeated", "not repeated again", "repeated", "this isn't repeated", "repeated", "is repeated" ]
    var arrayWithoutDuplicates = [ "not repeated", "not repeated again","this isn't repeated", "isn't repeated" ]

    XCTAssert(hasDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates), "There ARE duplicates")
    XCTAssert(hasDuplicates(arrayWithoutDuplicates) == false, "There AREN'T any duplicates")

    // Shows an error: Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'String'        
    XCTAssert(Array.hasDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates), "There ARE duplicates")
    XCTAssert(Array.hasDuplicates(arrayWithoutDuplicates) == false, "There AREN'T any duplicates")
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or is it a bug in XCode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extend typed Arrays in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `Array` as a type without specifying the generic parameter:

Replace:

```
Array.hasDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates)
```

with

```
Array<String>.hasDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates)
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought the function would get infer it from the parameter.

Comment: Oh my god, I will save this bookmark forever! Thanks!