# What's the difference between Optional<T> and optional types in Swift? Extending Optional to carry error information?

Tags: cocoa, error-handling, programming-languages, swift, option-type

> Update - there is no difference between Optional and optional types
>   in Swift - they are the same thing.

So in Swift they introduced the `Type?` construct, that creates an optional type which "forces" the programmer to check if the value actually exists.

Also, in Swift there is no exception handling.
But there is this built-in optionality mechanism.

This optional feature `?` is just an `Optional<T>` enum behind the scenes inspired from Haskell's `Maybe`.

I was wondering if there was any way of passing error information through the optional type.
Can `"abc123".toInt()` return error information through the optional type `Int?` ? Could this replace Exceptions or NSError? Of course Cocoa still uses (and will use?) the NSError pattern.

Playing in the playground, I found this piece of code in the Swift "header":

```
protocol Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension T? : Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

Basically this adds a readonly property `description` to ANY optional type. This would be super powerful (and could lead to many problems, I guess).

But after trying to extend myself the `T?` I get an error:

```
Non-nominal type 'T?' cannot be extended
```

So why didn't they add a property to all optional types to carry with them error information? Wouldn't it be useful? I mean, you could return a tuple if you want multiple return types...

Answer (score 1):

this is already part of the language

```
extension Optional : DebugPrintable {

    /// A textual representation of `self`, suitable for debugging.
    var debugDescription: String { get }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionals basically allow you to check whether or not a variable is nil. It's not meant to have an error message. For example take this Objective-C snippet:

```
if(self.someProperty == nil){
    self.someProperty = [[PropertyClass alloc] init]
}else{
    //property is not nil.
}
```

In swift you would do something like this:

```
var someProperty : PropertyClass?
if(someProperty){
    //property is not nil 
}else{
    //property is nil.
}
```

The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_312) say:

> Optional chaining in Swift is similar to messaging nil in Objective-C, but in a way that works for any type, and that can be checked for success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

`Option` in swift is like `Option` in Scala (`Maybe` in Haskell): It represents a value that may be absent.

What you're looking for is something like the `Try` or the `Either` monads from Scala, which represent two possible states of a computation, typically a `Success` or a `Failure`.

This would be a different algebraic data type, beyond the purpose of an optional value.

Ultimately, since swift doesn't have full-fledged monads in the standard library, I think the default error handling pattern will stay the classic Cocoa `NSError` one.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift), the correct syntax is:

```
extension Optional : Printable {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<T>` is the definition of Optionals (see below). `Type?` is just the syntactic sugar for creating the type.

```
enum Optional<T> {
  case None
  case Some(T)
}
```

From the *Swift Programming Language* iBook, the two declarations below are equivalent

```
var optionalInteger: Int?
var opTionalInteger: Optional<Int>
```