# Omitting function argument declaration for Closure in Swift

Tags: closures, swift

In "Functions and Closures" section of "The Swift Programming Language", it says "When a closure’s type is already known, such as the callback for a delegate, you can omit the type of its parameters, its return type, or both. Single statement closures implicitly return the value of their only statement."

```
numbers.map({ number in 3 * number })
```

How does it know the argument passed in is called number?

Is the following code correct in terms of how map may be implementing it?

e.g.

```
func map(callback:(number:Int) -> Int) {

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question after the edit. I have updated the answer with some information, perhaps it helps ...

Comment: Hi Martin, I am trying to figure out what the map function declaration looks like.  That is, if I want to create a function that can take a closure like the above, how should I define that?

Comment: I have added some example for functions taking a closure as an argument. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Boon cmd-clicking any function will bring you to it's declaration (either it's source code, if it's a class of your own; or a header, if it's an implementation by Apple).

Answer (score 2):

A closure expression generally has the form

```
{ (param_1 : type_1, ..., param_n : type_n ) -> return_type in
    statements
}
```

When the closure type is known, you can omit the parameter types, the return type
and also the parentheses around the parameters:

```
{ param_1, ..., param_n in
    statements
}
```

So to answer your question: The `in` keyword separates the parameters from the 
statements, therefore in your example, `number` is the (only) parameter.

Note that only (instance or class) methods use *external (named) parameters*, but (normal)
functions and closures do not. So it makes no difference if you write

```
let clo = { number in 3 * number }
let foo = clo(1) // foo = 3
```

or

```
let clo = { x in 3 * x }
let foo = clo(1) // foo = 3
```

and

```
numbers.map(clo)
```

applies the closure to each element of the array and returns an array of the
return values.

An implementation of `map` could look like this (I took and modified the code from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028208/1187415):

```
extension Array {
    func myMap<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> U[] {
        var result = U[]() // start with empty result array
        for item in self { // iterate over all items of the array
            let tmp = transform(item); // map this element ...
            result.append(tmp) // ... and append the mapped element to the result array
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

`myMap` is an instance method that takes one argument of type `(T) -> U`
and applies it to all elements of the array itself.

A simpler example for a function (without generics) taking an integer array and a closure as arguments would be

```
func myMapp(array: Int[], transform:(Int)->Int) -> Int[]
{
    var result = Int[]() 
    for item in array { 
        let tmp = transform(item);
        result.append(tmp)
    }
    return result
}
```

Then you can do

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let mapped2 = myMapp(numbers, { (number) in 3 * number })
```