# How to implement flatten as an extension on an Array without type casting?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

```
extension Array {
  func flatten<T>() -> T[] {
    let xs = (self as Any) as Array<Array<T>>
    return xs.reduce(T[](), +)
  }
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure if all those casts are required.

Is there a better way?

For comparison, [here](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift/blob/master/ExSwift/Array.swift#L655) is the implementation in one of the swift extension libraries. I'm not sure if they have it all figured out too -- their implementation begins with the following comment:

> //  There's still some work to do here

Comment: if it works, then it belongs on code review, if it is broken it belongs here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extend typed Arrays in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift)

Comment: Why have you posted this identical question on at least 2 stack exchange sites?

Comment: There is no need to implement `flatten` at all. `reduce` already _is_ `flatten`. So is `join`, for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't extend a specific type of a generic type in Swift:

```
extension Array<Int> {
}
```

> > error: non-nominal type 'Array' cannot be extended

But you can write a function that takes a specific type of array. If you want to flatten an array of arrays (`Array<T[]>`, `T[][]` or Array>) your functions signature would look like this:

```
func flatten<T> (array: Array<T[]>) -> T[]
```

It takes an array of arrays of `T` and returns an array of `T`. You can then use your approach with `reduce`:

```
func flatten<T> (array: Array<T[]>) -> T[] {
    return array.reduce(T[](), +)
}
```