# Extending Array to check if it is sorted in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to extend Array class so that it can know whether it is sorted (ascending) or not. I want to add a computed property called `isSorted`. How can I state the elements of the Array to be comparable?

My current implementation in Playground

```
extension Array {
  var isSorted: Bool {
    for i in 1..self.count {
      if self[i-1] > self[i] { return false }
    }
    return true
  }
}

// The way I want to get the computed property
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].isSorted //= true
[2, 1, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8].isSorted //= false
```

**The error** `Could not find an overload  for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Of course, I still got an error because Swift doesn't know how to compare the elements. How can I implement this extension in Swift? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement flatten as an extension on an Array without type casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564249/how-to-implement-flatten-as-an-extension-on-an-array-without-type-casting)

Comment: You can't extend `Array<Comparable>`, but you can implement a function that operates on `Array<Comparable>`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24565627/1489997

Comment: @Sebastian I think the link that you gave is quite different than my intention. It's pretty easy to make category for this kind of thing in obj-c, so I thought it should be as trivial in Swift.

Comment: @IkhsanAssaat this is not any easier in Objective C. You still have to find a way to compare elements, and ObjC doesn't give you a magical function to do that. I suggest you try writing such a function in Objective C, then maybe you'll understand why.

Comment: @Kevin: The problem is easier in Objective-C since an `NSArray` can only store objects, and you can ask them whether they implement a protocol or respond to a selector (`compare:`). Also, you can force casting in Objective-C. With Swift, the problem is harder as Swift doesn't allow you to "work around" the compiler. Also, there are `@objc` protocols and non-`@objc` protocols and you can only check whether a type conforms to the later, but `Comparable` is non-`@objc`. That's why `let foo = (bar as Any) as? Comparable` doesn't work: the compiler does not allow you to "trick" it.

Comment: (Re: `Comparable`: it also has a type constraint, something that doesn't exist in Objective-C. That's the real reason `let foo = (bar as Any) as? Comparable` doesn't work, like `var foo: Comparable` doesn't work either.)

Comment: @DarkDust Yes, you can put a method on all arrays, and hope they happen to have the right contents.

Comment: @Kevin: You can check the items. With `conformsToProtocol:` and `respondsToSelector:`. No hoping involved.

Comment: @Kevin What I meant by easy is by doing what @DarkDust mentioned, checking with `respondsWithSelector:` and/or checking that both class are the same class https://gist.github.com/ixnixnixn/fcd905fcdee58847ff18

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The alternative solution to a free function is to do what Swift's built-in `Array.sort` and `Array.sorted` methods do, and require that you pass a suitable comparator to the method:

```
extension Array {
    func isSorted(isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for i in 1..<self.count {
            if !isOrderedBefore(self[i-1], self[i]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

[1, 5, 3].isSorted(<) // false
[1, 5, 10].isSorted(<) // true
[3.5, 2.1, -5.4].isSorted(>) // true
```

Comment: Note that this actually fails for the example provided in the question: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].isSorted(<)`, because it doesn't handle repeated values.

Comment: I think you want to change `if !isOrderedBefore(self[i-1], self[i])` to `if isOrderedBefore(self[i], self[i-1])` to fix the problem pointed out by nschum.

Comment: Be careful, this solution would crash with empty arrays. I would add a guard checking that it isn't an empty array

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 4.2 and later you can cobble together [`allSatisfy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2996794-allsatisfy) and [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) with some sequence slicing:

```swift
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func isAscending() -> Bool {
        return zip(self, self.dropFirst()).allSatisfy(<=)
    }

    func isDescending() -> Bool {
        return zip(self, self.dropFirst()).allSatisfy(>=)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

In Swift 2.0 you can now extend protocols!

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Comparable {

    public var isSorted: Bool {

        var previousIndex = startIndex
        var currentIndex = startIndex.successor()

        while currentIndex != endIndex {

            if self[previousIndex] > self[currentIndex] {
                return false
            }

            previousIndex = currentIndex
            currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
        }

        return true
    }

}

[1, 2, 3, 4].isSorted // true
["a", "b", "c", "e"].isSorted // true
["b", "a", "c", "e"].isSorted // false
[/* Anything not implementing `Comparable` */].isSorted // <~~ Type-error
```

Note that because we're using `Indexable.Index` instead of a simple `Int` as an index we have to use a while-loop instead, which looks a bit less pretty and clear.

Comment: And for Swift 3, `Generator` becomes `Iterator` and `someIndex.successor()` becomes `self.index(after: someIndex)`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can extend the `Sequence` protocol for a more generic solution:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func isSorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        var iterator = makeIterator()

        guard var previous = iterator.next() else {
            // Sequence is empty
            return true
        }

        while let current = iterator.next() {
            guard try areInIncreasingOrder(previous, current) else {
                return false
            }

            previous = current
        }

        return true
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element : Comparable {
    func isSorted() -> Bool {
        return isSorted(by: <)
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything you did here to make an iterator, get its next elements, conditionally unwrap them and loop, is actually exactly what `for` does. This could just be `for current in self { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have incorporated [`allSatisfy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2996794-allsatisfy), but not [`adjacentPairs`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/AdjacentPairs.md), which makes this so easy that this extension may not be warranted.

```swift
import Algorithms

public extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
  /// Whether the elements of the sequence are in order.
  @inlinable var isSorted: Bool { adjacentPairs().allSatisfy(<=) }
}
```

```swift
let random = Int.random(in: 1...(.max))
let stride = stride(from: -random, through: random, by: random)
XCTAssert(stride.isSorted)
XCTAssertFalse(stride.reversed().isSorted)
```

However, it's very common to want to use a property of the elements for this, not the elements themselves:

```swift
import Algorithms

public extension Sequence {
  /// Whether the elements of this sequence are sorted by a common `Comparable` value.
  @inlinable func isSorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> Bool {
    try isSorted(by: comparable, <=)
  }

  /// Whether the elements of this sequence are sorted by a common `Comparable` value,
  /// and sorting closure.
  @inlinable func isSorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ areInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> Bool {
    try adjacentPairs().allSatisfy {
      try areInIncreasingOrder(comparable($0), comparable($1))
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct TypeWithComparable {
  let comparable: Int
}

let random = Int.random(in: 1...(.max))
let stride =
  stride(from: -random, through: random, by: random)
    .lazy.map(TypeWithComparable.init)
XCTAssert(stride.isSorted(by: \.comparable))
XCTAssert(stride.reversed().isSorted(by: \.comparable, >=))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adaptation, a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768486/5316459) that will work in Swift 4

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element: Comparable {
    func isSorted(isOrderedBefore: (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool  {
        for i in 1 ..< self.count {
            if isOrderedBefore(self[i], self[i-1]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible solution to me is a combination of NSAddict's and Wes Campaigne's answer. I.e. combine the advantage of being able to extend protocols and to pass comparator functions as arguments. This eliminates the restrictions both to use it only with arrays and to constrain it to elements conforming to `Comparable` protocol.

```
extension CollectionType
{
    func isSorted(isOrderedBefore: (Generator.Element, Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool
    {
        var previousIndex = startIndex
        var currentIndex = startIndex.successor()

        while currentIndex != endIndex
        {
            if isOrderedBefore(self[previousIndex], self[currentIndex]) == false
            {
                return false
            }

            previousIndex = currentIndex
            currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

This can be used on any `Collection` type and sorting criteria can be defined according to your needs.

Comment: And for Swift 3 replace `someIndex.successor()` with `self.index(after: someIndex)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Swift 4 that won't crash when `self.count` is equal or less than 1:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    func isSorted(by isOrderedBefore: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for i in stride(from: 1, to: self.count, by: 1) {
            if !isOrderedBefore(self[i-1], self[i]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

This snippet supposes that an array of 1 or 0 elements is already sorted.

The reason to start with 1 in the for-loop range is: In case self.count <= 1, the loop will be skipped, a small performance increase. Using `stride` instead of `..<` avoids the crash when the upper bound is < than the lower bound of a range.

Here are some examples:

```
[1, 2, 3].isSorted(by: >) // true
[3, 2, 2].isSorted(by: >=) // true
[1, 4, 7].isSorted(by: {x, y in
    return x + 2 < y * y
}) // true

let a: [Int] = [1]
a.isSorted(by: <) // true


let b: [Int] = []
b.isSorted(by: >) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Summarising previous answers there is a smallest universal Array extension to check:

```swift
extension Array {
    func isSorted(_ predicate: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) -> Bool {
        guard count > 1 else { return true }
        return (try? zip(self, self.dropFirst()).allSatisfy(predicate)) == true
    }
}

// Standard types

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].isSorted(<) // true
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5].isSorted(<) // false

[10, 5, 4, 3, 1].isSorted(>) // true
[10, 20, 4, 3, 1].isSorted(>) // false


// Custom types

struct MyStruct {
    let i: Int
}

let items = [MyStruct(i: 1), MyStruct(i: 2), MyStruct(i: 3), MyStruct(i: 10)]
let sorted = items.isSorted { $0.i < $1.i } // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple function without arguments, like sort() or sorted() in Swift:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {
    func isSorted() -> Bool {
        guard self.count > 1 else {
            return true
        }

        for i in 1..<self.count {
            if self[i-1] > self[i] {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic function, [`zip()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip), can provide a shortcut for implementation.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    var isSorted: Bool {
        guard count > 1 else {
            return true 
        }

        let pairs = zip(prefix(count - 1), suffix(count - 1))

        return !pairs.contains { previous, next in
            previous > next
        }
    }
}

[0, 1, 1, 2].isSorted  // true
[0, 2, 2, 1].isSorted  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

@kAzec's answer seems to not working when elements are equal. This is because areInIncreasingOrder(a, a) must be false according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice/2298431-sort#discussion).

The following should work fine.

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func isSorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool)
        rethrows -> Bool {
        var it = makeIterator()
        guard var previous = it.next() else { return true }
        
        while let current = it.next() {
            if try !areInIncreasingOrder(previous, current) &&
                areInIncreasingOrder(current, previous) {
                return false
            }
            previous = current
        }
        return true
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
    func isSorted() -> Bool {
        return isSorted(by: <)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun. This supports duplicated elements that are equal as well:

```
extension Sequence {
    var neighbors: Zip2Sequence<Self, DropFirstSequence<Self>> {
        zip(self, dropFirst())
    }
    func isSorted<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> Bool {
        try isSorted(predicate, by: <)
    }
    func isSorted<T: Comparable>(
        _ predicate: (Element) throws -> T,
        by areInIncreasingOrder: (T, T) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> Bool {
        try neighbors.allSatisfy {
            try areInIncreasingOrder(predicate($0), predicate($1)) ||
            predicate($0) == predicate($1)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
    var isSorted: Bool { isSorted(by: <) }
    func isSorted(
        by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> Bool {
        try neighbors.allSatisfy {
            try areInIncreasingOrder($0, $1) || $0 == $1
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
[1,2,2,3].isSorted         // true
[3,2,2,1].isSorted(by: >)  // true
```

---

```
struct Test {
    let id: Int
}

[1,2,2,3].map(Test.init).isSorted(\.id)          // true
[3,2,2,1].map(Test.init).isSorted(\.id, by: >)   // true
```