# Usage of protocols as array types and function parameters in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to create a class that can store objects conforming to a certain protocol.  The objects should be stored in a typed array. According to the Swift documentation protocols can be used as types:

> Because it is a type, you can use a protocol in many places where other types are allowed, including:
>
> - As a parameter type or return type in a function, method, or initializer
> - As the type of a constant, variable, or property
> - As the type of items in an array, dictionary, or other container

However the following generates compiler errors:

> Protocol 'SomeProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

How are you supposed to solve this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: Equatable {
    func bla()
}

class SomeClass {
    
    var protocols = [SomeProtocol]()
    
    func addElement(element: SomeProtocol) {
        self.protocols.append(element)
    }
    
    func removeElement(element: SomeProtocol) {
        if let index = find(self.protocols, element) {
            self.protocols.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift there is a special class of protocols which doesn't provide polymorphism over the types which implement it. Such protocols use Self or associatedtype in its definition (and Equatable is one of them). In some cases it's possible to use a type-erased wrapper to make your collection homomorphic. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38569499/3541063) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **Swift 5.7 / Xcode 14** this can now elegantly be solved using `any`.

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol: Equatable {
    func bla()
}

class SomeClass {
    var protocols = [any SomeProtocol]()
    
    func addElement(element: any SomeProtocol) {
        protocols.append(element)
    }
    
    func removeElement(element: any SomeProtocol) {
        if let index = find(protocols, element) {
            protocols.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to use a [any Protocol] array as a parameter value to a function that expects [Protocol]? I was running into that issue working with charts. A method wanted [Plottable] and I had a class where I need to specify the return as [any Plottable] because it could have been an array of Int or Double. The method wouldn't accept my [any Plottable] array though.

Answer (score 55):

You've hit a variant of a problem with protocols in Swift for which no good solution exists yet.

See also [Extending Array to check if it is sorted in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602595/extending-array-to-check-if-it-is-sorted-in-swift), it contains suggestions on how to work around it that may be suitable for your specific problem (your question is very generic, maybe you can find a workaround using these answers).

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the moment. Nate's solution is working but doesn't solve my problem entirely.

Answer (score 36):

You want to create a generic class, with a type constraint that requires the classes used with it conform to `SomeProtocol`, like this:

```
class SomeClass<T: SomeProtocol> {
    typealias ElementType = T
    var protocols = [ElementType]()

    func addElement(element: ElementType) {
        self.protocols.append(element)
    }

    func removeElement(element: ElementType) {
        if let index = find(self.protocols, element) {
            self.protocols.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you instantiate an object of that class?

Comment: Hmmm... This way locks you into using a single type that conforms to `SomeProtocol` -- `let protocolGroup: SomeClass<MyMemberClass> = SomeClass()`

Comment: This way you could only add objects of class `MyMemberClass` to the array?

Comment: or `let foo = SomeClass<MyMemberClass>()`

Comment: @snod Yeah, which isn't what you're looking for. The issue is `Equatable` conformance - without that you can use your exact code. Maybe file a bug/feature request?

Comment: I need the `Equatable` conformance because otherwise you can't search the array using the find function. A workaround could be to iterate manually over the array and compare pointers

Answer (score 19):

In Swift there is a special class of protocols which doesn't provide polymorphism over the types which implement it. Such protocols use `Self` or `associatedtype` keywords in their definitions (and `Equatable` is one of them).

In some cases it's possible to use a type-erased wrapper to make your collection homomorphic. Below is an example.

```
// This protocol doesn't provide polymorphism over the types which implement it.
protocol X: Equatable {
    var x: Int { get }
}

// We can't use such protocols as types, only as generic-constraints.
func ==<T: X>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a.x == b.x
}

// A type-erased wrapper can help overcome this limitation in some cases.
struct AnyX {
    private let _x: () -> Int
    var x: Int { return _x() }

    init<T: X>(_ some: T) {
        _x = { some.x }
    }
}

// Usage Example

struct XY: X {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

struct XZ: X {
    var x: Int
    var z: Int
}

let xy = XY(x: 1, y: 2)
let xz = XZ(x: 3, z: 4)

//let xs = [xy, xz] // error
let xs = [AnyX(xy), AnyX(xz)]
xs.forEach { print($0.x) } // 1 3
```

Answer (score 13):

The limited solution that I found is to mark the protocol as a class-only protocol. This will allow you to compare objects using '===' operator. 
I understand this won't work for structs, etc., but it was good enough in my case.

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    func bla()
}

class SomeClass {

    var protocols = [SomeProtocol]()

    func addElement(element: SomeProtocol) {
        self.protocols.append(element)
    }

    func removeElement(element: SomeProtocol) {
        for i in 0...protocols.count {
            if protocols[i] === element {
                protocols.removeAtIndex(i)
                return
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this allow duplicate entries in `protocols`, if `addElement` is called more than once with the same object?

Comment: Yes, arrays in swift may contain duplicate entries. If you think that this may happen in your code, then either use the Set instead of array, or make sure that array doesn't contain that object already.

Comment: You can call `removeElement()` before appending the new element if you wish to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I mean how you control your array is up in the air, right? Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 8):

The solution is pretty simple:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func bla()
}

class SomeClass {
    init() {}

    var protocols = [SomeProtocol]()

    func addElement<T: SomeProtocol where T: Equatable>(element: T) {
        protocols.append(element)
    }

    func removeElement<T: SomeProtocol where T: Equatable>(element: T) {
        protocols = protocols.filter {
            if let e = $0 as? T where e == element {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the important thing: the OP wants the protocol to inherit `Equatable` protocol. It makes huge difference.

Comment: @werediver I don't think so. He wants to store objects conforming to `SomeProtocol` in a typed array. `Equatable` conformance is required only for removing elements from array. My solution is an improved version of @almas solution because is can be used with any Swift type that conforms to `Equatable` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that your main aim is to hold a collection of objects conforming to some protocol, add to this collection and delete from it. This is the functionality as stated in your client, "SomeClass". Equatable inheritance requires self and that is not needed for this functionality.  We could have made this work in arrays in Obj-C using "index" function that can take a custom comparator but this is not supported in Swift. So the simplest solution is to use a dictionary instead of an array as shown in the code below. I have provided getElements() which will give you back the protocol array you wanted. So anyone using SomeClass would not even know that a dictionary was used for implementation.

Since in any case, you would need some distinguishing property to separate your objets, I have assumed it is "name". Please make sure that your do element.name = "foo" when you create a new SomeProtocol instance. If the name is not set, you can still create the instance, but it won't be added to the collection and addElement() will return "false".

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var name:String? {get set} // Since elements need to distinguished, 
    //we will assume it is by name in this example.
    func bla()
}

class SomeClass {

    //var protocols = [SomeProtocol]() //find is not supported in 2.0, indexOf if
     // There is an Obj-C function index, that find element using custom comparator such as the one below, not available in Swift
    /*
    static func compareProtocols(one:SomeProtocol, toTheOther:SomeProtocol)->Bool {
        if (one.name == nil) {return false}
        if(toTheOther.name == nil) {return false}
        if(one.name ==  toTheOther.name!) {return true}
        return false
    }
   */

    //The best choice here is to use dictionary
    var protocols = [String:SomeProtocol]()


    func addElement(element: SomeProtocol) -> Bool {
        //self.protocols.append(element)
        if let index = element.name {
            protocols[index] = element
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func removeElement(element: SomeProtocol) {
        //if let index = find(self.protocols, element) { // find not suported in Swift 2.0


        if let index = element.name {
            protocols.removeValueForKey(index)
        }
    }

    func getElements() -> [SomeProtocol] {
        return Array(protocols.values)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a **not** pure-pure Swift solution on that blog post:
http://blog.inferis.org/blog/2015/05/27/swift-an-array-of-protocols/

The trick is to conform to `NSObjectProtocol` as it introduces `isEqual()`.
Therefore instead of using the `Equatable` protocol and its default usage of `==` you could write your own function to find the element and remove it.

Here is the implementation of your `find(array, element) -> Int?` function:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {

}

func find(protocols: [SomeProtocol], element: SomeProtocol) -> Int? {
    for (index, object) in protocols.enumerated() {
        if (object.isEqual(element)) {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note: In this case your objects conforming to `SomeProtocol` must inherits from `NSObject`.