# Why do I get the error “Protocol … can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements”?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, self, protocol-extension

I wrote an extension onto `Int` as below.

```
extension Int {
    func squared () -> Int {
        return self * self
    }
}

print(10.squared()) // works
```

The above code works. Now I want to extend the `IntegerType` protocol so that Int, UInt, Int64, etc would all conform. My code is as below.

```
extension IntegerType {

    func squared () -> IntegerType { // this line creates error

        return self * self

    }
}
```

I get error:

> Protocol 'IntegerType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has) question and its video & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888560/usage-of-protocols-as-array-types-and-function-parameters-in-swift) question, still couldn't understand. I only understood that there is some `associatedType` which in this case is `Self` but couldn't connect the dots. I feel like also my lack of knowledge on the `Generics` subject is also a reason...

Can someone elaborate a bit on the subject and why does the extension create an error?

Comment: Also be sure to see [this Medium post](https://buildingvts.com/advanced-swift-protocols-d683cae12caf) it offers **great** insight about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function return type can only be a concrete `Type`.

The point is Type. **Anything struct, class or Protocols that are completely defined in themselves are pure Type.** **However when a protocol or struct depend on another Generic Type Placeholder such as T, then this is a partial type.**

Type are a data construct that compiler has to allocate certain memory.

So something like this:

`let a = Array<T>()` or `let b = T` is not sufficient information for the compiler to deduce at compile time.

Hence, this wont work.

```
  extension IntegerType {

    func squared () -> IntegerType { // this line creates error

        return self * self

    }
}
```

Here, IntegerType is a partial type. It is a generic protocol that only when conformed can then we know the exact type. Similar to Array. Array itself is not a type. Its a generic container. Only when someone creates it with Array() or Array()... then it has a type.

The same happened with you.

```
public protocol IntegerType : _IntegerType, RandomAccessIndexType {
```

then again,

```
public protocol RandomAccessIndexType : BidirectionalIndexType, Strideable, _RandomAccessAmbiguity {
@warn_unused_result
    public func advancedBy(n: Self.Distance) -> Self
```

then again,

```
   public protocol _RandomAccessAmbiguity {
    associatedtype Distance : _SignedIntegerType = Int
   }
```

Hence, as RandomAccessIndexType has Self requirement meaning until and unless someone conforms to it, Self is unknown placeholder. It is partial Type.

Since IntegerType conforms to the RandomAccessIndexType and _RandomAccessAmbuiguity which requires Distance associated type too.

Hence you cant do this too

```
let a: IntegerType = 12
```

Again IntegerType needs to know Self and Distance (associatedType).

Int however provides the details like so

```
public struct Int : SignedIntegerType, Comparable, Equatable {
    /// A type that can represent the number of steps between pairs of
    /// values.
    public typealias Distance = Int
```

Hence you can do such

```
let a:Int = 10
```

because it provides Self for SignedIntegerType and Distance for its other counterpart.

Simply put it:

**A partial type cannot be used where a concrete type can be. A partial type are good for other generics and constraining them.**

Comment: What's with the underscore?

Comment: They are part of swift internal implementation protocols. Although you can access them publicly, i would not do that.

Comment: I means what's the difference between `_IntegerType` & `IntegerType`?

Comment: Any protocol that follows _ signifies that this protocol should not be used publicly. This is part of the Swift Standard Library implementation. Time and again they will revise this internal protocol in a way it does adhere to the high level view. And if you do use this publicly although Xcode will not suggest, when the internals change you might need to redo.

Comment: It's been more than year. And I've slowly I've started to use generics for my code and have a better understanding.  2 Questions:

1. _is not sufficient information for the compiler to deduce at compile time._

I don't get that. I mean the type of a generic parameter is inherently unknown in all its functions. Why can't it be the same for the extension you wrote. Why is that any different?

2. Additionally you said: _A function return type can only be a concrete Type._ But many functions return `T`. Doesn't that contradict what you just said?

Comment: @Honey: 1. It is not true that the type of a generic parameter is unknown. The compiler resolves the type of generic parameters based on what type its callers specify. 2. It's true that some protocols declare funcs that return `T`, but those protocols are always adopted by types that define `T`. They do this either concretely, by saying that `T` is some concrete type, or by declaring their own generic parameter, putting the responsibility of specifying the concrete type onto _their_ caller. Either way, `T` gets associated to a concrete type. If it didn't, the compiler would prohibit it.

Answer (score 7):

You just have to return `Self`

edit/update:

Note: You can extend all numeric types (Integer & FloatingPoint) in Swift 4 extending the Numeric Protocol

**Swift 4**

```
extension Numeric {
    func squared() -> Self {
        return self * self
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 3**

```
extension Integer {
    func squared() -> Self { 
        return self * self
    }
}
```

Comment: Leo, can you take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338692/why-do-i-get-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-beca#comment87254598_39351340) on the accepted answer? I'm thinking that answer is somewhat wrong and yours is correct. Am I right? Can you elaborate a bit? Also other than the new `Numeric` protocol, is there anything new in Swift4 which would affect this question?

Comment: @Honey there is nothing to elaborate. The accepted answer explains why did you get the error, which is what you asked. I just provided the solution to your question. Note that it is up to you to decide which one to mark as correct.