# Generics Protocol as Type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

How I can create a protocol variable. My goal is a protocol will be have a function with a generic type and I'm using `associatedtype` which is accessing to `Class` and the function will be return generic type. Example declaration below:

```
public protocol ComponentFactory {
   associatedtype T // A class and that class can be inherit from another so I need define generic type here
   func create() -> T
}
```

I want to declare a variable for this protocol like that:

```
fileprivate var mComponentFactoryMap = Dictionary<String, ComponentFactory>()
```

At this line I receive a error: 
`Protocol 'ComponentFactory' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I see from Android, actually from kotlin they have a declare for `interface` like:

```
private val mComponentFactoryMap = mutableMapOf<String, ComponentFactory<*>>()
```

Any guys can help me, how I can declare this from Swift?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338692/why-do-i-get-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-beca

Comment: Swift needs to know what the type of `T` will be in `mComponentFactoryMap`. Without knowing what type it is, the compiler can't do the required type checking.

Comment: @GaryMakin I've comment on that line `associatedtype`. Do that like `associatedtype T: Component // Component is a class`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Sorry but from that link I just know about pure Type I don't figure out how to defined like what my question? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this from few months ago with descriptions below. Please check it and give me another solution if you have.

Firstly, make some change for `Protocol`. At `associatedtype T` should be change to `associatedtype Component` and `Component` is a class which will be inherited from another class (important step).

```
public protocol ProComponentFactory {
    associatedtype Component
    func create() -> Component?
}
```

Second, I will make a `Generic Struct` with inheritance from `ProComponentFactory`:

```
public struct ComponentFactory<T>: ProComponentFactory {
    public typealias Component = T
    public func create() -> T? { return T.self as? T }
}
```

Well done, for now you can define a variable as I example in my question above:

```
fileprivate var mComponentFactoryMap = Dictionary<String, ComponentFactory<Component>>()
```

As well for any class was inherit from `Component` and variable `mComponentFactoryMap` can using extension inside.