# Why a protocol with typealias is not sufficient for the associated type requirements?

Tags: swift, generics

I am aware of the [limitations](https://medium.com/@NilStack/swift-world-type-erasure-5b720bc0318a) of using a `typealias` in my protocol. It prevents me from doing something like:

```
protocol Provider {
    associatedtype R

    func receiveString(s: R)
}

struct ProviderManager {

    let providers: [(Provider)]
}
```

Because the `ProviderManager` doesn't know the type of `R`, it complains with the error message:

> Protocol 'Provider' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

However, why can't I introduce an intermediary protocol that specifies the associated type? Something like:

```
protocol Provider {
    associatedtype R

    func receiveString(s: R)
}

protocol StringProvider: Provider {
    typealias R = String
}

struct ProviderManager {
    let providers: [(StringProvider)]
}
```

The above still doesn't work even though implementing the `StringProvider` protocol works as intended:

```
final class MyStringProvider: StringProvider  {
    func receiveString(s: String) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The above implementation of `MyStringProvider` works. But I still can't use `StringProvider` in an array. Why not?

Comment: In swift 4, define `protocol StringProvider: Provider where R == String { }`

Comment: Sure, but the problem for which I am asking the question is still the same.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24888560/5555803) and its answers

Answer (score 0):

> Protocol 'Provider' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

To remove this error you have to create your struct in this way:

```
struct ProviderManager<P: Provider> {
    var providers: [P]
}
```

**EDIT:**

And you can instantiate your manager like this:

```
let manager: ProviderManager = ProviderManager(providers: [MyStringProvider()])
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. If I try: `let manager: ProviderManager<StringProvider>`, I get "Using 'StringProvider' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'StringProvider' is not supported". I would need to pass one of the specific class implementations of the `StringProvider`, which defeats the point of passing a `P: StringProvider` type.

Comment: @ADev I have edited my answer hope it helps for what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That almost works the way I wanted except that I don't want to pass only instances of `MyStringProvider`. Instead, I wanted instances of the `StringProvider` protocol. Say I have `MyStringProvider` and `MyOtherStringProvider`. With your solution I can't do `let manager: ProviderManager = ProviderManager(providers: [MyStringProvider(), MyOtherStringProvider()])`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variable/property of type "protocol". You can create variable/property (in your case an array) of some type that conforms to your protocol. Try this:

```
protocol StringProvider : Provider where R == String {
}
struct StringProviderStruct : StringProvider {
    func receiveString(s: String) {
    }
}
struct ProviderManager {
    let providers: [StringProviderStruct]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I can't have a "protocol" for children of `StringProviderStruct` like I would with an abstract class in Java. I prefer the "AnyCollection" type-erased wrapper solution over this one.

Comment: Again: you cannot **instantiate** a protocol. you can instantiate struct or class conforming to protocol. This simply cannot work: `let providers: [(protocol-not-class-or-struct)]`

Comment: Sorry for not communicating my intent properly. I understood that we can't do what I was trying in my question. My comment was trying to convey that, because we can't, the "AnyCollection" type-erased wrapper solution is more appropriate for my use case over yours.