# AnyObject and generics in Swift

Tags: swift

This code fails to compile with Swift 5.1

```
import Foundation

protocol SomeClassProtocol: AnyObject {}
class SomeClass: SomeClassProtocol {}

class GenericClass<T:AnyObject> {
    weak var t: T?
    init(t: T) {
        self.t = t
    }
}

let test = GenericClass<SomeClassProtocol>(t: SomeClass())
```

The error is

`'GenericClass' requires that 'SomeClassProtocol' be a class type`

Does the compiler really need a class type here instead of a class-only protocol?

Comment: I believe you're encountering the same problem as this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888560/usage-of-protocols-as-array-types-and-function-parameters-in-swift - in short, not all `protocol` types can be used as generic type arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Though the syntax is the same (a colon), protocol inheritance is not the same thing as protocol conformance. Protocols do not conform to protocols; only types can conform to protocols. (`AnyObject` is not special in this regard; your question is good but the title isn't getting at the issue.)

In your example:
Your `T` needs to conform to `AnyObject`. `SomeClassProtocol` does not conform to `AnyObject`. But any types that conform to `SomeClassProtocol` will conform to `AnyObject`.

So you need to pick which of these you really want:

  1.

```swift
let test = GenericClass( t: SomeClass() )
```

(`test` is a `GenericClass<SomeClass>`.)

  2.

```swift
class Class {
  weak var object: AnyObject?
  init(object: AnyObject) {
    self.object = object
  }
}

Class( object: SomeClass() )
```

You do have the option of subclassing, if that would be useful.

```swift
class GenericClass<T: AnyObject>: Class {
  var t: T? {
    get { object as? T }
    set { object = newValue }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does protocol-inheritance not imply or assert that a protocol conforms to another protocol? In other languages like Java and C# then if you have `interface IFoo : IBar` then `IBar` is covariant with `IFoo`, but in Swift if you have `protocol Fooable : Barable` you cannot substitute in a `Fooable` value where a `Barable`-typed parameter argument is expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the compiler really need a class type here instead of a class-only protocol?

Yes, it does. I think the problem is just understanding what this means:

```
class GenericClass<T:AnyObject>
```

That means: "To resolve GenericClass, the parameterized type T must be some type that *is a class*." Examples would be UIView, NSString, etc.

Okay, so:

```
let test = GenericClass<SomeClassProtocol>(t: SomeClass())
```

So, SomeClassProtocol is none of those; it isn't the name of a class. It's the name of a protocol.

A further difficulty may be understanding protocols as types. They are *not* really full-fledged types.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to specify `T` explicitly.

Change your code from this:

```
let test = GenericClass<SomeClassProtocol>(t: SomeClass())
```

To this:

```
let test = GenericClass(t: SomeClass())
```