# Protocol conforming to type with associated value

Tags: swift, protocols

I've got the following snippet:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol: Identifiable where ID == UUID {
    var id: UUID { get }
}


var test: [MyProtocol] = []
```

> Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Why doesn't this work? Shouldn't the `where ID == UUID` remove the ambiguity the error is concerned with? Am I missing something here?

I think this question is similar to this one: [Usage of protocols as array types and function parameters in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888560/usage-of-protocols-as-array-types-and-function-parameters-in-swift)

However, I would have assumed that adding `where ID == UUID` should fix the problem? Why is that not the case?

Thanks!

### Edit

So, this problem has occurred while experimenting with `SwiftUI` and struct data models. I've always used classes for any kind of data model but it seems like `SwiftUI` wants to get you to use structs as often as possible (I still don't see how that's realistically possible but that's why I'm experimenting with it).

In this particular case, I tried to have a manager that contains structs that all conform to `MyProtocol`. For example:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol: Identifiable where ID == UUID {
    var id: UUID { get }
}

struct A: MyProtocol { // First data model
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}

struct B: MyProtocol { // Second data model
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    var myData: [MyProtocol]
}

...
```

I don't actually have to declare `Identifiable` on `MyProtocol` but I thought it would be nicer and cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is not a current feature of Swift. Once there is an associated type, there is always an associated type. It doesn't go away just because you constrain it. And once it has an associated type, it is not concrete.

There is no way to "inherit" protocols this way. What you mean is:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var id: UUID { get }
}
```

And then you can attach Identifiable to structs that require it:

```
struct X: MyProtocol, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
}
```

(note that no `where` clause is required.)

There is no Swift feature today that allows you to say "types that conform to X implicitly conform to Y." There is also no Swift feature today that allows for an Array of "things that conform to Identifiable with ID==UUID." (That's called a generalized existential, and it's not currently available.)

Most likely you should go back to your calling code and explore why you require this. If you post the code that iterates over `test` and specifically requires the `Identifiable` conformance, then we may be able to help you find a design that doesn't require that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have a particular use case for this, I was just experimenting with different ways of using structs instead of classes. I added information to the question

Comment: "but it seems like SwiftUI wants to get you to use structs as often as possible." This isn't true. SwiftUI seems to be pushing us very hard towards using classes for the Model, since only classes can observed (which is key to how SwiftUI works). SwiftUI wants (requires) you to use structs for Views. If you watch the WWDC videos, the data models were classes.

Comment: "I don't actually have to declare Identifiable on MyProtocol but I thought it would be nicer and cleaner." Why? Adding protocols that you don't use isn't cleaner in Swift.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up something. I meant to say `view models` are supposed to be structs. That's what is suggested (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/233/, starting minute 36). And this comes with so many problems, in my (amateur) opinions. That's why I'm looking into using structs, to figure it out.

Comment: "Why? Adding protocols that you don't use isn't cleaner in Swift." - Again sorry, unfortunate wording on my part. Using `Identifiable` allows you to leave out the `id` parameter in SwiftUI structs like `ForEach`. You don't have to conform to it, but it makes it cleaner inside the View

Comment: Right, but you can assign `Identifiable` to the *types* you want. You don't have to put it on the protocol (which turns the protocol into a PAT). This is very similar to the mistake of adding `Equatable` to protocols (rather than to types). You generally don't mean that, and it causes the same problems.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is MyProtocol itself. It's hard to imagine what algorithms it's driving. In order to get the kind of ViewModel pattern I think you're describing, I would expect it to be a struct, not a protocol. Once you created `[MyProtocol]`, the only things you can call on its contents are things provided by the protocol (things that both A and B provide). That suggest what you really want is a struct that just holds those values.

Comment: In the video you linked, they do exactly what I'm describing at 39:50.

Comment: I think you're right. `A` and `B` from my example would be `data models` in a real-world scenario. I've been thinking about them as `view models` that are directly pushed to the views. What you're saying makes sense. I think `MyProtocol`, `A` and `B` should actually be classes (because they represent the data models/layer). For `SwiftUI` views I would then create separate `view model` structs that I initialize using these data model classes.

Comment: The original reason (I think; it's been weeks of trying these things) I probably started to mix models and view models is data consistency. Using the method I described in the last comment, you have the problem of keeping the view model synced because it's just a "copy" of the model. But I now realize you don't have to do that. Whenever the model changes, `SwiftUI` recreates the view hierachy and therefore recreates the view model struct. Does this make sense? If yes, then you've just helped me figure out the most frustrating architectural problem I've ever faced :D

Comment: Yes, I think you're exactly on the right track there.The whole idea of Swift Views is that they're thrown away and reconstructed. "State" variables give the illusion of state, but they're really just things that are remembered between instances of the view hierarchy. The key point of a ViewModel is not to hold a source of truth; it's just there to transform the source of truth (the model) into a shape that the View would like.

Comment: (But also: this is pretty early days in SwiftUI. We're all flailing around a little bit looking for the patterns that will really work in large-scale projects. Even Apple hasn't built enough of those to know for certain what patterns work best. So nothing here is definitive, but it's what I've found so far.)

Comment: Dang, that was the missing piece in my head. Thank you so much! 
Yeah, it will definitely change over time. I mainly try all this to gain a sense of clear code architecture (everything I've done so far is terribly chaotic and a nightmare to work with). And I love the idea behind SwiftUI so I started there. And a basic understanding of these concepts helps so much with everything, even outside of SwiftUI, I think