# Typescript object declaration where each prop has its own generic

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a more dynamic object typing. Right now I have the following:

```
interface MyGeneric<T> {
  value: T
}

interface MyObject {
  [name: string]: MyGeneric<any>;
}
```

But I want to abstract it to look more like this:

```
interface MyGeneric<T> {
  value: T
}

interface MyObject {
  [name: string]<T>: MyGeneric<T>;
}
```

This syntax does not work, but what I want would allow each prop on the object to have its own generic type.

Any advice on what this might look like?

Comment: This reminds me of [a similar question I asked but for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61750544/8289918). I don't think this is possible because the `MyGeneric`s in `MyObject` would have completely different types unless they have the same type parameter (e.g. `any`). For example, what type would `MyObject.foo` be? TypeScript does not have a type that would be able to describe this.

Comment: How would you add the type for the generic in the second example? You may want to add details about your use case so we can try to help find a solution using a related type like mapped types.