# How to create type for all 3 possible argument definitions and call a function that expects either of those

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, markdown-it

(types coming from @type/markdown-it)
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/markdown-it/lib/index.d.ts#L93

I'd like to create arguments types for the possible arguments to the `markdown-it` `use` method which is typed as this:

```
type PluginSimple = (md: MarkdownIt) => void;
type PluginWithOptions<T = any> = (md: MarkdownIt, options?: T) => void;
type PluginWithParams = (md: MarkdownIt, ...params: any[]) => void;
```

I have a react hook that I would like to hand in markdown-it plugins like this:

```
type Plugin = MarkdownIt.PluginSimple |
  [MarkdownIt.PluginWithOptions, {}?] | 
  [MarkdownIt.PLuginWithParams, ...any[]]
type Plugins = Plugin[]

function useMarkdown(source: any, plugins?: Plugins) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    plugins?.forEach(plugin => md.use(...plugin))
  }, [md, plugins])
}
```

First of, I did not know how to add the template argument to the second plugin definition.

This does not work:

```
[<T = any>MarkdownIt.PluginWithOptions<T>, T?]
```

But mostly I would like the TS compiler to recognise that that the use of `md.use(...plugin)` is safe.
It complains, that the argument needs to support

`Expected at least 1 argument, but git 0 or more`
`An argument for 'plugin' was not provided.`
`Type` Plugin `must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an interator`

Changing my line to handle the array cases manually:

```
plugins?.forEach(plugin => Array.isArray(plugin) ? md.use(...plugin) : md.use(plugin))
```

Removes the iterator error message but leaves the other too for the usage of `...plugin`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63652147/8289918. Also, the `must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method` error is correct and your first code will result in a runtime error. This is because `Plugin` can be a `SimplePlugin`, which isn't iterable and cannot be spread.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all three cases to `md.use` with spread syntax, so they all have to be tuples.  In the case of `PluginSimple`, the arguments are a tuple of length `1`.

```
type Plugin = [PluginSimple] |
  [PluginWithOptions, any] | 
  [PluginWithParams, ...any[]]
type Plugins = Plugin[]
```

Now for the error about requiring 1 or more arguments, we can make sure that typescript knows that there is always at least one argument by destructuring the first entry in the tuple separately from the rest.  Based on our union type, we know that `main` is always defined and is one of the plugin types, while rest is `any[]` and will be `[]` for the simple plugin.

```
function useMarkdown(source: any, plugins: Plugins = []) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    plugins.forEach(plugin => {
      const [main, ...rest] = plugin; 
      md.use(main, ...rest)
    })
  }, [md, plugins])
}
```

This isn't perfect because we aren't enforcing a match between the `PluginWithOptions` and its specific option type, but hopefully it's good enough for your use case.  For more advanced typing, I would think about defining your own plugin object which holds a plugin and its arguments rather than using tuples.