# different compoted Generic Values in Array of Generics

Tags: typescript

I have something similar to this type in typescript:

```
interface Test<V> {
  MyArray: Record<string, A<V>>
}
```

I need new Computed `A<V>` type for each key:value in Object MyArray, Is this possible ? I mean every value created By generic `A<V>` is different in each key.

Comment: please show an example that creates a value of this type

Comment: Is this the same question as [Typescript object declaration where each prop has its own generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63652147/8289918)?