# how to check if an array is sorted in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, sorting

how to check if an array is sorted?

I am sorting using sort descriptors. Is there any API to check if an array is already in sorted order in Swift/Objective-C.

Thanks

Comment: Sort the array and see if the result is the same. Or just sort it - now you know it's sorted.

Comment: Or even better — _don't_ use sort descriptors. Sort the Swift way instead.

Comment: matt, just curious: what's the Swift way?

Comment: Using a closure with sort, I'd assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is no frame work, simply iterate truth the array, and check if the current element greater or equal (or less or equal, or which kind of sorting you look for) is. This is the easiest way. Look please at this Question [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602595/extending-array-to-check-if-it-is-sorted-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a built in way to check if an array is already sort descriptors. The best way to check is to iterate through the array and check if each element should come before the element precedes it (using whatever definition of "should come before" you want for your sort). If you're sorting custom objects, you can write some sort of `compareTo` method that compares two objects of your class, which will make it convenient to check using the method I described.