# Swift: loop over array elements and access previous and next elements

Tags: swift

In Swift, I want to loop over an array and compare each element to the previous and/or next. For each comparison I will either produce a new element or nothing. Is there "functional" way of doing this?

An example could be that I have an array of `Int` and want to find all "local minimums.

I could do it sequencially like this

```
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
var i = 1
var r: [Int] = []

while i < a.count - 1 {
    if a[i] < a[i+1] && a[i] < a[i-1] {
        r.append(i)
    }
    i += 1
}

print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

I wonder if there is a more simple or direct way to do it.

Comment: Related: [Check whether integers in array are consecutive or in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469194/).

Comment: I reckon your way of doing it is the best one compared to all the answers :)

Answer (score 12):

Generally, one can use `dropFirst()` and `zip()` to traverse over adjacent array elements
in parallel. Here is a simple example which produces the array of increments between the
array elements:

```
let a = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 8, 10 ]

let diffs = zip(a.dropFirst(), a).map(-)
print(diffs)
// [1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 2, 2, -4, -2, 5, 2]
```

To compute the indices of local minima we can iterate over `a`, `a.dropFirst()`
and `a.dropFirst(2)` in parallel. `enumerated()` is used to keep track of the
array offsets, and `flatMap()` (renamed to `compactMap()` in Swift 4.1) is used
to pick only those indices which correspond to a local minimum:

```
let a = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 8, 10 ]

let localMins = zip(a.enumerated().dropFirst(), zip(a, a.dropFirst(2))).flatMap {
    $0.element < $1.0 && $0.element < $1.1 ? $0.offset : nil
}
print(localMins) // [6, 11]
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a variation of the original Q that I hope might help someone else. I needed to map every item in the array while considering the previous and next values:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    var withPreviousAndNext: [(Element?, Element, Element?)] {
        let optionalSelf = self.map(Optional.some)
        let next = optionalSelf.dropFirst() + [nil]
        let prev = [nil] + optionalSelf.dropLast()
        return zip(self, zip(prev, next)).map {
            ($1.0, $0, $1.1)
        }
    }
}
```

And the not so pretty way to use that with original Q:

```swift
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
let indices = a.enumerated().withPreviousAndNext.compactMap { values -> Int? in
    let (prev, cur, next) = values
    return (cur.1 < (prev?.1 ?? Int.min) && cur.1 < (next?.1 ?? Int.min)) ? cur.0 : nil
}
indices // [6,11]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the `while` loop and `i` with a `for` loop and `stride`.

```
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
var r: [Int] = []

for i in stride(from: 1, to: a.count - 1, by: 1) {
    if a[i] < a[i+1] && a[i] < a[i-1] {
        r.append(i)
    }
}

print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

You can get real fancy with a filter but this isn't nearly as readable as the above code:

```
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
let r = a.enumerated().dropFirst().dropLast().filter { $0.1 < a[$0.0 + 1] && $0.1 < a[$0.0 - 1] }.map { $0.0 }
print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also iterate over indices and compare like this,

```
for i in a.indices.dropFirst().dropLast()
{
    if a[i] < a[a.index(after: i)],
            a[i] < a[a.index(before: i)] {
        r.append(i)
    }
}
print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

Or, something like this,

```
let result = a.indices.dropLast().dropFirst().filter { i in
    return a[i] < a[a.index(after: i)] &&
            a[i] < a[a.index(before: i)]
}
print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

Or, short,

```
let result = a.indices.dropLast()
                      .dropFirst()
                      .filter { a[$0] < a[$0 + 1] &&
                                a[$0] < a[$0 - 1] }
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flatMap

```
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
let r = a.enumerated().flatMap { (_ offset: Int, _ element: Int) -> Int? in
    guard offset > 0 else { return nil }
    if element < a[offset-1] && element < a[offset+1] {
        return offset
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple for-loop over the range be sufficiently readable and maintainable? You could just cache the intermediate values as you iterate, so that you only access one element of the array in each iteration. If you wanted to generalize this for any comparable type, you could implement it as an extension of Array:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    func localMinimums() -> [Int] {
        var minimums = [Int]()

        var currentValue = self[0]
        var nextValue = self[1]
        for index in 1..<(self.count - 1) {
            let previousValue = currentValue
            currentValue = nextValue
            nextValue = self[index + 1]
            if currentValue < nextValue && currentValue < previousValue {
                minimums.append(index)
            }
        }

        return minimums
    }
}

let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]
let r = a.localMinimums()
print(r)
// [6, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Martin R's answer is smart, though I try answering using the other way.

```
let a = [ 1,2,2,3,5,4,2,5,7,9,5,3,8,10 ]

func withPrevAndNext<T, U>(`default`: U, _ f: @escaping (T, T, T) -> (U)) -> (T) -> (U) {
    var previous: T?
    var current: T?

    return { next in
        defer { (previous, current) = (current, next) }
        guard let prev = previous, let curt = current else { return `default` }
        return f(prev, curt, next)
    }
}

let r = a.enumerated().compactMap(withPrevAndNext(default: .none) { prev, curt, next -> Int? in
    curt.1 < prev.1 && curt.1 < next.1 ? curt.0 : .none
})

print(r)
// [6, 11]
```