# Swift: Assignment group number to member of Tuple in array of Tuples

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, grouping

I have some array of Tuples with definition like this:

`[(description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)]` and sorted by decrease of `.criterion`.

I need to add `.group` member to each Touple in this array based on matching values of `.criterion`.

Value of `.group` is `1...n` increasing by 1. If several Tuples have the same value of `.criterion`, then they will have the same value of `.group`.

If Tuple have unique `.criterion`, then it only one will have unique `.group` value.

I'm trying to do this in code below:

```
func appendingGroup(_ input: [(description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)]) -> [(description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)] {
var output: [(description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)] = []
var index = 1
while index < input.count - 1 {
    if input[index].criterion != input[index + 1].criterion && input[index].criterion != input[index - 1].criterion {
        print(index)
        output[index].group = index
    }
    index += 1
}
return output}
```

This is based on @Nicolai Henriksen question [Swift: loop over array elements and access previous and next elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476485/swift-loop-over-array-elements-and-access-previous-and-next-elements)

But I have `[]` in my `output`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are encouraged to use a struct rather than a tuple. It makes life much easier.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But I'm new in Swift and don't have much knowledge right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get empty `output` is because you didn't modify it.

Try change

`var output: [(description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)] = []`

to

`var output = input`

**Full**:

```
typealias Type = (description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)

func appendingGroup(_ input: [Type]) -> [Type] {
    guard input.count > 2 else { return input } // without this check app will crash for arrays that are less than 2
    var output = input
    var index = 1

    while index < input.count - 1 {
        if input[index].criterion != input[index + 1].criterion && input[index].criterion != input[index - 1].criterion {
            output[index].group = index
        }

        index += 1
    }

    return output
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's works...but in my `input` I have initial value `.group = 0` and in output all `.group` is **0**.

Comment: @George Have you tried to debug? I guess that for your array if conditions (`if input[index].criterion != input[index + 1].criterion && input[index].criterion != input[index - 1].criterion`) is not satisfy.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @George If my answer helped you then consider to accept it :) Thanks

Comment: Almost done... But still don't know how to be with the last element of array! It'sout of the scope!

Comment: `var index = 0
      var group = 1
      while index < input.count - 1 {
            if input[index].criterion == input[index + 1].criterion {
                  output[index].group = group
                  } else {
                        group += 1
                        output[index].group = group
           }
           index += 1
      }`

Answer (score 0):

Finally working solution based on @Bohdan Savych comment:

```
    typealias Type = (description: [String], criterion: Int, relative: Double, average: Int, type: String, group: Int)

    func appendingGroup(_ input: [Type]) -> [Type] {
          guard input.count > 2 else { return input } // without this check app will crash for arrays that are less than 2
          var output = input
          var index = 0
          var group = 1
          while index < input.count - 1 {
                if input[index].criterion == input[index + 1].criterion {
                      output[index].group = group
                } else {
                      output[index].group = group
                      group += 1
                } 
                index += 1
          }
          if input[input.count - 1].criterion == input[input.count - 2].criterion {
                output[input.count - 1].group = output[input.count - 2].group
          } else {
                output[input.count - 1].group = (output[input.count - 2].group) + 1
          }
          return output
    }
```