# Spilt Array into pairs

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to split array into pairs. I am able to split into consecutive pair but I want to split into pair which includes previous value as mentioned in **Results**

Logic to split in consecutive pair, which I tried.

```
extension Array {
func chunks(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
        Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)])
    }
}
```

Array:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Results:

```
[["1", "2"], ["2", "3"], ["3", "4"], ["4", "5"], ["6", "7"], ["7", "8"], ["8", "9"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: loop over array elements and access previous and next elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476485/swift-loop-over-array-elements-and-access-previous-and-next-elements)

Comment: If the chunk size was 4, would the correct result be `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
let a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let pairs = Array(zip(a, a.dropFirst())).map {[$0.0, $0.1] }

print(pairs)
```

That outputs

> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]

### Edit:

If you want arbitrary chunk-size, you could write the extension like this:

```
extension Array {
    func chunks(_ chunkSize: Int, includePartialChunk: Bool = true) -> [[Element]] {
        var indexes = Array<Int>(stride(from: 0, to: count, by: chunkSize - 1))
        if includePartialChunk,
           let last = indexes.last,
           last < count - 1 {
            indexes.append(count-1)
        }
        return zip(indexes, indexes.dropFirst()).map {Array(self[$0.0...$0.1])}
    }
}
```

Use the parameter `includePartialChunk` to tell the function if you want to include a "partial chunk" at the end when the array size is not an even multiple of the chunk-size. If true (The default) it returns a last chunk that is smaller than chunkSize but goes to the end of the array. If false, it only returns full-sized chunks, but will skip array elements at the end that don't fit into a full-sized chunk.

(I'll have to study Leo's `UnfoldSequence` version and see if I can adapt my code to that.)

Comment: A similar approach should work in most languages that support functional programming constructs (Kotlin, Haskell, etc.)

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you wanted to allow variable sized chunks. Is that a requirement for your problem?

Comment: for me, it will work with fixed size.

Comment: If you allow a variable chunkSize, it isn't clear what to do if the array count is not an even multiple of chunkSize. Do you stop when you wind up with chunks smaller than chunksize? If so you would not include the elements in the last, partial chunk in the result. Or do you return a final, partial chunk?

Comment: Actually in my case, I need pair sequence when array count is > 2. So, above solution is fine.

Comment: Leo, code is *impossible* to read in comments. Would you mind posting your version as a second answer? I'm not familiar with `UnfoldSequence`.

Comment: @DuncanC done [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70807337/2303865)

Comment: @DuncanC btw initializing a new array before mapping it is pointless `let pairs =  zip(a, a.dropFirst()).map { [$0.0, $0.1] }`

Comment: @DuncanC btw I have updated the answers to support different lengths as well as to include the tail or not

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to the question but the elements of the sequence should be computed lazily. You should use Swift `UnfoldSequence` type as follow:

```
extension Collection {
    var unfoldedNeighbors: UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex else { return nil }
            guard let end = index(start, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: endIndex) else {
                return nil
            }
            defer { formIndex(after: &start) }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
    var neighborsSubsequences: [SubSequence] {
        .init(unfoldedNeighbors)
    }
    var neighborsArrays: [[Element]] {
        unfoldedNeighbors.map([Element].init)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for neighbors in numbers.unfoldedNeighbors {
    print(neighbors)
}
```

---

If you need control the number of elements of each subsequence and also if it includes the tail or not:

```
extension Collection {
    func unfoldedNeighbors(limitedTo length: Int, includesTail: Bool = false) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex else { return nil }
            guard let end = index(start, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: endIndex) else {
                if includesTail {
                    defer { formIndex(&start, offsetBy: length-1, limitedBy: endIndex) }
                    return self[start...]
                }
                return nil
            }
            defer { formIndex(&start, offsetBy: length-1, limitedBy: endIndex) }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
    func neighborsSequences(limitedTo length: Int, includesTail: Bool = false) -> [SubSequence] {
        .init(unfoldedNeighbors(limitedTo: length, includesTail: includesTail))
    }
    func neighborsArrays(limitedTo length: Int, includesTail: Bool = false) -> [[Element]] {
        unfoldedNeighbors(limitedTo: length, includesTail: includesTail).map([Element].init)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for neighbors in numbers.unfoldedNeighbors(limitedTo: 3, includesTail: true) {
    print(neighbors)
}
```

This will print:

> [1, 2, 3]
> [3, 4, 5]
> [5, 6, 7]
> [7, 8, 9]
> [9, 10]

---

```
let neighborsSequences = a.neighborsSequences(limitedTo: 3, includesTail: true)  // [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]] of type [Array<Int>.SubSequence]
let neighborsArrays = a.neighborsArrays(limitedTo: 3, includesTail: true)        // [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]] of type [[Int]]
```

Comment: I need to study this. Thanks for the tip. (Voted)

Comment: You can achieve lazy evaluation simply with `zip(a, a.dropFirst()).lazy.map { [$0.0, $0.1] }`

Comment: @MartinR what about mapping the elements. Isn’t it better to iterate the tuples of the zip2sequence and not initializing a new array for each element?

Answer (score 1):

This operation goes by [`windows`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Windows.md). It does exactly what you've requested, for count 2…

```swift
import Algorithms

Array(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"].windows(ofCount: 2))
```

…but it's unclear if it does what you want for other counts.

Answer (score 0):

At least, it's easy to read and o(n) complexity...

```swift
extension Int {
    var nextIndex: Int {
        self + 1
    }
}

extension Array {
    var splitedByCouples: [[Element]] {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            return []
        }
        
        let couplesMaxCount = self.count / 2
        var source = self
        var couples: [[Element]] = []
        
        while couples.count < couplesMaxCount {
            let couple = [source[.zero], source[.zero.nextIndex]]
            couples.append(couple)
            source.removeSubrange(0...1)
        }
        if source.count == 1 {
            couples.append([source.last!])
        }
        return couples
    }
}
```

And usage like below:

```swift
// prints "[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]"
print([1,2,3,4,5,6,7].splitedByCouples)

// prints "[]"
print(Array<String>().splitedByCouples)

// prints "[[0.0]]"
print([Double.zero].splitedByCouples)

// prints "[[true, false], [true, false]]"
print([true, false, true, false].splitedByCouples)
```