# Iterating over every pair of adjacent elements in an array

Tags: swift

Is there a standard library solution or a package for iterating over an array where on every iteration, instead of getting an element, you get a **tuple of one element and the next element**?

In other words, you get a window covering two (or more) elements and on every iteration the window slides one element over. That's what I think [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998245/iterate-over-a-window-of-adjacent-elements-in-python) for Python is (not sure).

Here's my kludge solution for a window of size 2:

```swift
for index in array.indices.dropLast() {
    let a = array[index]
    let b = array[index + 1]
}
```

The number of iterations in this case would be `array.count - 1` and every element would occur twice, except for the first and last elements.

It seems to me like there ought to be a standard, generic solution for this -- something like `for (a, b) in array.slidingWindow(of: 2) { ... }` -- but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476485/swift-loop-over-array-elements-and-access-previous-and-next-elements) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is implemented in Algorithms as `adjacentPairs`.](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/AdjacentPairs.md)