# How can i use XCTAssertTrue to check it an Array is sorted

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

i want to check if a collection is sorted in my UnitTest  using XCTest, does swift iOS provide any such framework or method.

```
let countrieds = ["Alabama","Benin","Alaska","Togo"]
    XCTAssertTrue(countrieds.sorted())
```

The above is just a sample and ofcourse i get the error below

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Bool'

i will be glad to be educated on how to use XCTest to determine if a collection is sorted.

Comment: XCTest offers nothing for this, so this is effectively a duplicate of [Extending Array to check if it is sorted in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602595/extending-array-to-check-if-it-is-sorted-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to test that is to do an assertEqual with your array.
For exemple:

```
let countries = ["Alabama","Benin","Alaska","Togo"]
XCTAssertEqual(countries, countries.sorted())
```

(In this exemple the test will return false obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```swift
XCTAssertTrue(countrieds == countrieds.sorted())
```

or

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(countrieds, countrieds.sorted())
```