# Swift Array Extension with Zip2

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I want to create an Array extension that does this:-

```
func pairs(tmp: [Any]) -> [(Any, Any)] {
    return Array(Zip2(tmp[0..<tmp.count-1], tmp[1..<tmp.count]))
}
```

which works fine, but if I wrap it in extension Array:-

```
extension Array {
    func pairs<T>() -> [(T, T)] {
        return Array(Zip2(self[0..<self.count-1], self[1..<self.count]))
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:-

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'Array<T>' that accepts an argument list of type '(Zip2<Slice<T>, Slice<T>>)'
```

(also, is the method signature correct? still trying to get my head around the generics syntax)

Comment: btw, you can write this slightly more succinctly as `func pairs() -> [(T, T)] { return Array<(T, T)>(zip(self, dropFirst(self))) }` – zip will only go as far as the shortest of the two sequences.

Comment: thanks; always good to see neater ways of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a bug (tested with Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.3 beta 2).
It compiles and works in a function, and even in a generic function:

```
func pairs<T>(tmp: [T]) -> [(T, T)] {
    return Array(Zip2(tmp[0..<tmp.count-1], tmp[1..<tmp.count]))
}
```

But it does not compile in an `Array` extension method.
As a workaround, you can specify the generic type explicitly in the constructor:

```
extension Array {
    func pairs() -> [(T, T)] {
        return Array<(T, T)>(Zip2(self[0..<self.count-1], self[1..<self.count]))
    }
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b = a.pairs()
println(b) // [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Also note that the `pairs()` method does not specify the placeholder type `<T>` again, see for example [How can I extend typed Arrays in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift).